# Can Storm's HdfsBolt flush data after a timeout as well?

Tags: bigdata, apache-storm

We are using Storm to process streaming data and store into HDFS. We have got everything to work but have one issue. I understand that we can specify the number of tuples after which the data gets flushed to HDFS using SyncPolicy, something like this below:

**SyncPolicy syncPolicy = new CountSyncPolicy(Integer.parseInt(args[3]));**

The question I have is can the data also be flushed after a timeout? For e.g. we have set the SyncPolicy above to 1000 tuples. If for whatever reason we get 995 tuples and then the data stops coming in for a while **is there any way that storm can flush the 995 records to HDFS after a specified timeout** (5 seconds)?

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

- Shay

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you send a tick tuple to the HDFS bolt, it will cause the bolt to try to sync to the HDFS file system. All this happens in the [HDFS bolt's execute function](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/external/storm-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/hdfs/bolt/HdfsBolt.java#L116).

To configure tick tuples for your topology, in your topology config. In Java, to set that to every 300 seconds the code would look like:

```
Config topologyConfig = new Config();
topologyConfig.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, 300);

StormSubmitter.submitTopology("mytopology", topologyConfig, builder.createTopology());
```

You'll have to adjust that last line depending on your circumstances.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to add this and get the code to compile. But looks like this sends a tuple to the topology. Is the refresh intended to work automatically (every 300 seconds in your code), or do we need to write some additional code to handle the tick and flush the data?

Comment: If memory serves, the tick tuple should trigger the flush. That's baked into the HDFS bolt. So the flush will happen at whatever interval you specify your topologies tick tuples to get sent out.

Comment: Its not doing an auto refresh, we are trying to find if there is a configuration or something thats needed. If any one knows, then any help would be awesome!

Comment: Btw...here's what we are seeing for now: The tick tuple looks like is being received as a regular tuple by the HDFS Bolt. So if we set it to 10 seconds then we are actually seeing a row with the value 10 in the output. There is no effect on the flush, that still happens based on the Sync Policy

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative solution for this problem,

First, lets clarify about sync policy, If your sync policy is 1000 ,then HdfsBolt only sync the data from 1000 tuple by calling hsync() method in execute() means it only clears the buffer by pushing data to disk, but for faster write disk may uses its cache and not writing to file directly.

The data is written to the file only when the size of data matches your rotation policy that need to specify at the time of bolt creation.

```
 FileRotationPolicy rotationPolicy = new FileSizeRotationPolicy(100.0f, Units.KB);
```

So for flushing the record the to file after timeout, Seperate your tick tuple from normal tuples in excecute method and calculate the time difference of both tuple, If the diff is greater than timeout period then write the data to file.

By handling tick tuple differently you can also avoid the tick tuple frequency written to your file.

See the below code for better understanding:

```
public class CustomHdfsBolt1 extends AbstractHdfsBolt {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomHdfsBolt1.class);
private transient FSDataOutputStream out;
private RecordFormat format;
private long offset = 0L;
private int tickTupleCount = 0;
private String type;
private long normalTupleTime;
private long tickTupleTime;

public CustomHdfsBolt1() {

}


public CustomHdfsBolt1(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public CustomHdfsBolt1 withFsUrl(String fsUrl) {
    this.fsUrl = fsUrl;
    return this;
}

public CustomHdfsBolt1 withConfigKey(String configKey) {
    this.configKey = configKey;
    return this;
}

public CustomHdfsBolt1 withFileNameFormat(FileNameFormat fileNameFormat) {
    this.fileNameFormat = fileNameFormat;
    return this;
}

public CustomHdfsBolt1 withRecordFormat(RecordFormat format) {
    this.format = format;
    return this;
}

public CustomHdfsBolt1 withSyncPolicy(SyncPolicy syncPolicy) {
    this.syncPolicy = syncPolicy;
    return this;
}

public CustomHdfsBolt1 withRotationPolicy(FileRotationPolicy rotationPolicy) {
    this.rotationPolicy = rotationPolicy;
    return this;
}

public CustomHdfsBolt1 addRotationAction(RotationAction action) {
    this.rotationActions.add(action);
    return this;
}

protected static boolean isTickTuple(Tuple tuple) {
    return tuple.getSourceComponent().equals(Constants.SYSTEM_COMPONENT_ID)
            && tuple.getSourceStreamId().equals(Constants.SYSTEM_TICK_STREAM_ID);
}


public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
    try {

        if (isTickTuple(tuple)) {
            tickTupleTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

            long timeDiff = normalTupleTime - tickTupleTime;

            long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeDiff);

            if (diffInSeconds > 5) {  // specify the value you want.
                this.rotateWithOutFileSize(tuple);

            }

        } else {

            normalTupleTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            this.rotateWithFileSize(tuple);
        }
    } catch (IOException var6) {
        LOG.warn("write/sync failed.", var6);
        this.collector.fail(tuple);
    }

}


public void rotateWithFileSize(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {

    syncHdfs(tuple);

    this.collector.ack(tuple);

    if (this.rotationPolicy.mark(tuple, this.offset)) {
        this.rotateOutputFile();
        this.offset = 0L;
        this.rotationPolicy.reset();
    }
}


public void rotateWithOutFileSize(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {

    syncHdfs(tuple);

    this.collector.ack(tuple);

    this.rotateOutputFile();
    this.offset = 0L;
    this.rotationPolicy.reset();

}

public void syncHdfs(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {
    byte[] e = this.format.format(tuple);

    synchronized (this.writeLock) {
        this.out.write(e);
        this.offset += (long) e.length;
        if (this.syncPolicy.mark(tuple, this.offset)) {
            if (this.out instanceof HdfsDataOutputStream) {
                ((HdfsDataOutputStream) this.out).hsync(EnumSet.of(SyncFlag.UPDATE_LENGTH));
            } else {
                this.out.hsync();
            }

            this.syncPolicy.reset();
        }
    }


}

public void closeOutputFile() throws IOException {
    this.out.close();
}

public void doPrepare(Map conf, TopologyContext topologyContext, OutputCollector collector) throws IOException {
    LOG.info("Preparing HDFS Bolt...");
    this.fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(this.fsUrl), this.hdfsConfig);
    this.tickTupleCount = 0;
    this.normalTupleTime = 0;
    this.tickTupleTime = 0;

}

public Path createOutputFile() throws IOException {
    Path path = new Path(this.fileNameFormat.getPath(),
            this.fileNameFormat.getName((long) this.rotation, System.currentTimeMillis()));
    this.out = this.fs.create(path);
    return path;
}
}
```

You can directly use this class in your project.

Thanks,

Comment: This will keep writing zero byte files in HDFS when there is no tuple but the topology is still running